# .htaccess login exclude one file and ip. For a whole server

Tags: .htaccess

I've seen numerous topics. with `.htaccess` excluding files or IP's but I just can't seem to fit it together.

I want to lock down our development server for the outside world. All (sub)domains on this server should be handled with one file.

- All visitors (clients) have to login
- Except inside our office
- Allow 1 file for everybody. Because someone used it as the source of an email signature...

I can get 2 out of 3 to work but not a combination of all 3.

This `.htaccess` is located in `/home/user/domains/.htaccess`
Individual websites also have their own `.htaccess` in their webroot `/home/user/domains/example.com/public_html/.htaccess` these websites are mostly WordPress or Magento. And so are there `.htacess` files

**Overview of the structure**

```
/home/user/.htaccess #the file I've put the code.
/home/user/domains/wordpress.example.com/public_html/.htaccess
/home/user/domains/magento.example.com/public_html/.htaccess
/home/user/domains/example.com/public_html/.htaccess
/home/user/domains/anotherwp.example.com/public_html/.htaccess
```

**The file I use**

```
AuthName "You shall not pass"
AuthUserFile /home/user/domains/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user

Order Deny,Allow
#doens't work for some reason
Allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx #Office IP

#This execption is here because some smartass included this in an email signature
<Files "email_logo.jpg">
  Allow from all
  Satisfy any
</Files>
```

Who can help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do all 3 requirements using `mod_setnenvif`:

```
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr ^192\.168\.0\. ALLOWED
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "email_logo\.jpg" ALLOWED

AuthName "You shall not pass"
AuthUserFile /home/user/domains/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user
Satisfy any
Order deny,allow
Deny from All
Allow from env=ALLOWED
```

Comment: Tanx for the answer, but the file doesn't appear to work. This file isn't in the webroot for clarity.

Comment: It can exist any where and this is actually a tested code. Are you getting auth dialog for `email_logo.jpg` also?

Comment: check update, I have retested this setup and there was not auth dialog for `email_logo.jpg` from any subdirectory in my testing.

Comment: Your solution does work if there is only 1 `.htaccess` I added a bit more information about the double `.htaccess` files in my question. Could you check again?

Comment: So you are saying it works for primary domain but doesn't work for subdomains? Can you clarify the problem you're facing?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47237/discussion-between-janw-and-anubhava)